# arduino (mega 2560) to graph numbers

Tags: graph, arduino

i am currently studying 3rd year CSE and have little to no background in electronics but i have suddenly taken an interest in robotics
i just started using arduino and its exciting. i got a bit of understanding of to code it (i know c and java). unfortunately i am lost when it comes to interfacing it with anything else other than arduino software. my teacher gave me a project to do as a begineer.

MY QUESTION: i was told to send a number (or sequence of numbers) to the arduino board. the board should blink the pin 13 LED (i know how to do this part) when it receives a number. then it should divide the number by two and send the result back to computer. here the computer must use "processing tool" to graph the number. 
        1. any help/hints are appreciated.
        2. any idea on what this "processing tool" is actually called? all i was told was it was a software to graph numbers.
        3. how to take output from arduino into another program as input?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processing tool is literally called Processing. It is a Java-based programmatic screen-drawing system that is very easy to use. Take a look at it [here](https://processing.org/).

Processing is much like Arduino in that it has the setup(), loop() architecture and is similar in syntax.

To get data from the Arduino to Processing, you will need to send serial data to the PC.